# pie chart in highchart with dynamic data

Tags: arrays, json, angular, highcharts

I want to create a pie chart with a dynamic data in highchart so I create this method :

```
pieData :any=[];
getPiedata() {
 this.service.getSales().subscribe(data => {
    this.sales=data ;

    for (var i = 0; i < this.sales.length; i++){
       this.pieData.push({
          "name" : this.sales[i][this.pienames],
          "y" : this.sales[i][this.piepercent]
       })
     }
    ;
    console.log("pie",this.pieData);
    return JSON.stringify(this.pieData);
 })
}
```

And this is the method PreparePiechart() :

```
PreparePiechart() {
this.pieOptions ={
   chart : {
     plotBackgroundColor: null,
     plotBorderWidth: null,
     plotShadow: false,
     type : 'pie'
   },
   title: {
     text: ''
   },

   series: [{
     name: 'Brands',
     colorByPoint: true,
     data: this.getPiedata()
   }]
 }}
```

The expected input in data is a json like that :

```
 [
  {name: "book1",
     y: 50
  }
  {name: "book2",
     y: 50
  }
  ]
```

And this is the ngOnInit() :

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.PreparePiechart()
 }
```

But I had an empty Pie chart ! How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is asynchronous. You could build the chart after the data is received. Try the following

```js
getPiedata() {
 this.service.getSales().subscribe(data => {
    this.sales = data ;

    for (var i = 0; i < this.sales.length; i++){
      this.pieData.push({
        "name" : this.sales[i][this.pienames],
        "y" : this.sales[i][this.piepercent]
      })
    }
    console.log("pie",this.pieData);
    this.preparePiechart(JSON.stringify(this.pieData));  // <-- create chart options here
 })
}

preparePiechart(pieData: any) {
  this.pieOptions = {
    chart : {
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotShadow: false,
      type : 'pie'
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Brands',
      colorByPoint: true,
      data: pieData
    }]
 }
}
```